# Is it possible to create a standalone distributed Swift Framework?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I have a scenario where I need to package some common code into a Swift only framework. I have found many tutorials on how to do this but all involve creating a framework within an iOS app. My goal is to:

1. Create a seperate Framework project
2. Build and produce a .framework file
3. Copy that single file(without all the source files) into some iOS app project, add it under "Linked Libraries" and use it.

Question: Is this possible or do I have to include all of the Classes that are part of the framework?

I have added a framework project to an iOS app and had success using it because all the source code was in the Framework project. I tried to copy that .framework file alone to a new project and use it but when trying to access the classes or instantiate the contents of the framework I couldn't even-though whatever needed to be declared as public was.

Appreciate any help...